# Route table in MVC storage location

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, routes

I know in MVC at the application launch time the RegisterRoutes method is called in the Application_Start eventhandler of the global.asax. There is a collection of routes called the RouteCollection that contains all the registered routes in the application. RegisterRoutes method registers the routes in this collection.
But I want to know where this route table is located is it in IIS. How can I locate it? For eg. I am running default MVC application where can I found this route table.

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
     RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
}

routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

Comment: Why are you referencing BundleConfig in your post?

Comment: Unclear what your asking. You question is about routes, but you code relates to bundles.

Comment: updated correct code.

Answer (score 1):

It's "in memory". That's why you have to register it each time your app starts. `RouteTable.Routes` is a static reference to a `RouteCollection`.

So you can just call `RouteTable.Routes` to access it.

Comment: yes its in memory,but where it actually stores is it in IIS?

Comment: You'll need to state what you are trying to do. There is a mismatch between what you are asking and what you must actually want.

Comment: i was asked a question in interview Where is route table stored.

Answer (score 0):

Well, before answering the question let me tell you that I think there is a confusion between Route and RouteTables. RouteTable is not stored anywhere, it a class by the way that stores the URL routes for your application. However, Routes are stored in a RouteTable.

So as I said, all the application Routes of are stored in RouteTable. The RouteTable is a global variable which is created when our MVC Application is started. This is shared across all the users using the application.

The RouteTable contains property by the name Routes (Routetable.Routes). It contains the collection of all the routes. We can add our own routes to this collection.

Reference from this link: [RouteTable storage](https://www.tektutorialshub.com/asp-net/routing-in-mvc/#where-do-the-routes-arestored)

Answer (score 0):

in Application memory of Server RAM where IIS is working.
and as mentioned above RouteTable.Routes is a static reference to a RouteCollection